# How to delete item from ListView in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have a ListView and I want to delete some items, I have not found a useful answer yet.

this is a XMAL :

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate >
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
               Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding PhoneNo}" 
               Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and listview :

```
public ObservableCollection<Contact> ContactList2 { get; set; }
```

I can easily add it, but I do not know how to delete it.

Comment: ObservableCollection has multiple remove methods .Remove(someInstanceoOfContact) .RemoveAt(someInt), etc...

Comment: If your ListView has the ItemSource equals to your ObservableCollection, then by removing an item from your collection it will be automatically removed from the listview (inotifypropertychanged should be implemented)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [context menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#context-actions)

XAML

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
  <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
           Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

code behind

```
public void OnDelete (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
    Contact contact = (Contact)mi.CommandParameter;
    ContactList2.Remove(contact);
}
```